# Laravel - Cannot get 500 status code while redirecting to a custom route

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel 8`.

I was reading the documentation on the following page: `HTTP Redirects`

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redirects

I have the following code which works well when both: `env('APP_DEBUG') == true/false` in terms of what the user sees: Custom error page or Laravel Debug page respectively.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Register the exception handling callbacks for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        if (!env('APP_DEBUG')) {
            // On Production, redirect to: /error
            $this->renderable(function (Exception $e, $request) {
                return redirect('/error');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when `env('APP_DEBUG') == false` (which makes that custom block of code under: `register` function to be reached), I properly get redirected to: `/error` but I need to get HTTPS status code: `500`.

I tried with `return redirect('/error', 500);` but when doing that I get the following:

[image]

instead of get redirected to: `/error` page.

Any idea on how to get redirected to: `/error` and get the status code: `500` at the same time?

Thanks.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Comment: that doesn't work for me because I need an actual redirection

Comment: You need to set the status code for /error page, not for redirect, the redirect will return a response with 301/302 status code.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: the redirect response is not going to let you set a status code that is not `201, 301, 302, 303, 307, 308`

Comment: thank you for the clarification.